# How to add a new folder in Windows 2008 Server Registry

Tags: windows-registry

I need to add a new registry entry.  But first I need an existing folder under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ in order to place that new entry into.  I don't see a way to create a new folder under SOFTWARE.  I'm new to messing with the registry outside of simple tweaks...I'm a C# Developer.  This key will be retrieved in some of our C# code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You right-click on SOFTWARE (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) and choose New -> Key then give it a name.  Then you right click on that and choose New -> XX Value, based on the type of entry you want to add.

Folders are the pictoral representative of a Key.  Entries under keys are called Values.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.. I was trying to create a registry `value` using the `win32api`. From your explanation it seems there are only 3 things `keys, values and data`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, they're not called folders, they're called Keys.  Secondly, don't create it under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE - the end user may not have write access to this key (e.g. if they're not a local admin).  Create it under HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead.  Thirdly, armed with this mighty knowledge, the following link should explain everything you need to know: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=create+registry+key+c%23&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=